# Mapping ring asteroids in Elite Dangerous by image processing

Tags: image-processing, algorithms, 3d

In the game Elite Dangerous, which is an online spaceflight-based sandbox game set in a procedurally-generated galaxy, one of the most profitable in-game occupations is mining commodities from asteroids in the rings of certain planets.  Because mining can be so profitable, it is widely used to gather in-game currency to fund other activities.  Many players do not actually enjoy mining, but engage in it solely to fund their preferred gameplay, so Credits per Hour are very important to them.

The content of the ring asteroids is constant,  as is their position in 3-dimensional space over time, however many rotate in-place at a constant rate around a constant axis.  Rings are effectively circles with no centre thousands of kilometers wide, and are around ten kilometers thick.

I *believe* that the pattern of asteroids in the rings may repeat, though the mineable content of the asteroids may not repeat, or may repeat over multiple repeats of the basic 'tile(s)'... Determining that is part of the point of this project.

Elite Dangerous logs many things that are encountered in-game, but ring mining activities are not logged, nor is there any coordinate system accessible to the players.

The mining process involves dropping out of supercruise (a rapid travel mechanism) near a ring, flying to that ring, and identifying suitable asteroids to mine, either by randomly prospecting nearby asteroids until suitable asteroids are found, or by pre-mapping high-yield asteroids by the expedient of screenshots, and using them in conjunction with fixed points of reference to orient oneself and find and mine each successive high-yield asteroid. There are a limited number of asteroid shapes, and all asteroids in a ring are similarly coloured, except when a pulse-wave scanner is used, which turns certain asteroids different colours according to their content.

Once mapped, a player could drop into a mapped area, and the companion software would highlight each asteroid according to its status, and point the player to the next most profitable asteroid.

So, that being the background, this is the problem that I wish to solve: I would like to write a companion application to Elite Dangerous that uses image processing techniques and optical character recognition to screen-scrape the relevant ring metadata.  Whenever a player running this companion app drops into a ring, it should use photogrammetry to locate the player within an existing map or begin constructing a new map.  Whenever an asteroid is prospected, the app should be able to log the asteroid's content and associate it with the relevant asteroid.

In order to write this application, (using C#.NET), I need to know the best approach to using photogrammetry to map a ring in as close to realtime as possible.  Are there any algorithms or APIs that would be particularly suitable for this task?  Do any of them lend themselves to GPU processing?  I would prefer free open source solutions, given that this will most likely be freeware.

I don't need to discuss OCR... just photogrammetry of the ring asteroids.

[Here is a video that includes footage of the rings in question from about 3' 35".](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=RM8Qcpx1K38)

[Here's a Google Drive folder-full of mining guide photos.](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=1rt0oAUrYniXZwaeXUPVWJMGZRU-E3BgI)

For example:

[image: Example asteroid image.]

The algorithm need not map the shape of each asteroid in any great detail, it need only place each asteroid reasonably accurately within 3d space.  The shape and position of asteroids is constant,with the exception of rotation, and the content of asteroids can be identified by position alone.  As some asteroids rotate very slowly, and are highly irregular in shape, attempting to identify the shape of the asteroids would be unnecessary work.

Additionally, since edge detection was mentioned, Elite Dangerous has a "night vision" mode which functionally highlights the edges of objects.  It is entirely acceptable to require players using the proposed application to activate that feature, since much mining is done with it activated anyway.

Comment: adding a screenshot of said rings might help

Comment: @MarcusMüller I've gone one better, and posted a link to a video that contains footage of ring mining.

Comment: nope, that's not actually better: I won't watch a video when I need a picture :) Please really add a picture. Annotate it with what you mean.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Have a look at the folder I've shared.  The video will show how some asteroids rotate, but otherwise may have the same shape as some others.  The yellow asteroids have been highlighted by the pulse wave scanner,  otherwise they are the same colour as all the rest.

Comment: Can you **really** pick one to three photos and annotate them, I really have no idea what to look for, and these are *a lot* of photos.

Comment: The whole point is that unless the asteroids are annotated by some process, be it by taking screenshots or in some app, you don't know - or can't remember - what rock has what... but once generated, they always have the same content for everyone.  The asteroids in each image with the white < > symbols is the one that has been prospected, and its content is shown on the bottom left panel.  Every one of these screenshots is a high-value asteroid amongst the other low value asteroids.  What I am trying to do is create my own 3D map of *all* the asteroids, so that I can annotate *that*.

Comment: You have no need to be able to distinguish between one asteroid and another for yourself, because even if there is a pattern and it does repeat, it's too large for a human to remember, and I'm not sure that the mineable quantities repeats when the physical arrangement repeats.

Comment: seriously, I can't even tell which rocks in your pictures are the same and which ones are different rocks. You're literally the only one on this platform with domain knowledge – it would *really* be valuable if you could bring yourself to just pick three different, random rocks and add their pictures directly to the question. And explain under which conditions you need to recognize them – e.g., still when looking at them from a different angle? Or is the angle fixable in some way? Really, narrow this down for us. I'm not going to try to make sense of hundreds of unannotated pictures.

Comment: I'm seriously a bit confused as why I have to beg for that.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm not asking any person to understand this... it takes players of the game many hours to learn to spot some types of resource-rich asteroid... I'm asking for help finding algorithms or APIs that will allow me to physically map the location of each asteroid as a ship moves through the asteroids, or correlate its position within a previously mapped volume. There are no coordinates available to players,  so it would have to be done by whatever is available on-screen.

Comment: I don't necessarily even need to be able to distinguish between the different shapes, just their positions and colours.

Comment: The asteroid field may be viewed from literally any direction, so the application would have to be able to correlate the positions of the objects it sees with a previously mapped volume which may not have been mapped from the same direction.

Comment: OK, giving up. Not looking at this question anymore before concrete example pictures of different asteroids and the same asteroid from different angles have been given.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm saying that the shape of the asteroids *doesn't matter at all* for purposes of my application.  The map need only be the *physical positions* of the asteroids.  I was actually thinking of reducing the resolution of the screenshots a lot to make them less detailed so that an algorithm would be forced to look at position alone.

Comment: How do you know the position of an object in 3D space if a) you can't identify it by it's look, and b) without understanding its shape? Again, your whole arguing I don't need a picture has cost the both of us more time than it would have you to select three pictures, so I'm completely muting this conversation for 48 hours.

Comment: So you want some way to have this companion app automatically recognize the placement of asteroids from the 2D view out your cockpit and somehow create the 3D map of exact positions based on some reference point in the background? That’s why the shape of the asteroids doesn’t matter to you?

Comment: @KipDeGraaf Exactly!  There is a reference point in the form of the planet it encircles 
as well as the hotspot marker, though that is more a HUD element, and it is possible to get an external view... but ultimately it is the position of the asteroids which matters.  You can have many asteroids with exactly the same models, with many different contents, but it is position that ultimately correlates with content... everything else just helps a human tell them apart.  The problem is that the asteroids rotate at different speeds, making them difficult to identify when showing a different aspect.